# Advanced MVVM scenario in UWP app - How to use a model class for multiple viewmodels?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I have been coding for over 4 years now... and time has come that I need to understand how to use MVVM in a perfect way, in order to be able to accomplish more difficult coding tasks.

More specifically, I would like to know how to use a model object for multiple viewmodels and views.

### Sample scenario

Let's have an app that has two views: the first with a list of `ItemModel` objects (that shows all the objects available) and another one that has a list that only contains the favorites ones.
The `ItemModel` has an **IsFavorite** boolean property to determine whether or not it is one.

Until today, I have always accomplished scenarios like this in this way:

> ItemModel class (a model-viewmodel class at the same time):

```
public class ItemModel : BaseBind   // This class implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemModel()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private bool isFavorite;
    public Boolean IsFavorite
    {
        get { return isFavorite; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isFavorite, value); OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    // All the model's and viewmodel's properties and functions are stored here...

    public void GenericFunc()
    {
        App.Current.AppViewModel.GenericAppFunc(this);
    }

    public void FavoriteFunc()
    {
        App.Current.AppViewModel.FavoriteAppFunc(this);
    }

    public ItemModel Clone()
    {
        // Cloning the item with "new" constructor...
    }
}
```

> AppViewModel class:

```
public class AppViewModel
{
    public AppViewModel()
    {
        // Initializing...
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> ItemsList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> FavoritesList { get; set; }


    public void UpdateFavorites()
    {
        FavoritesList.Clear();

        foreach (var it in ItemsList)
        {
            if (it.IsFavorite) FavoritesList.Add(it.Clone());
        }
    }

    public void GenericAppFunc(ItemModel item)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void FavoriteAppFunc(ItemModel item)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

> First view, with all items listed:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemsList, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ItemModel">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemTitle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <Button Content="Generic func" Click="{x:Bind GenericFunc}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

> Second view, with only favorites listed:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.FavoritesList, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ItemModel">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemTitle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <Button Content="Favorite func" Click="{x:Bind FavoriteFunc}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

This is my way of doing it all... having two completely independent lists and cloning objects everytime the user navigates to the favorites view.

It works, it always did it... BUT this is definitively NOT a good pattern.

To summarize, this is what I'm doing till now...

[image]

...and this is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

In order to have lightweight models like this...

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Boolean IsFavorite { get; set; }

    // Only the model's properties and functions are stored here...

}
```

...and use it for multiple viewmodels/views.

Best regards and thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can do exactly what you wrote in the light weight models,  but let me get something clarified, are you saying that you want to use/access the same list of items in multiple viewModels? also, why don't you use the item click event on the ListView, so you can move the event handlers in the viewmodel using relay commands?

Answer (score 1):

In UWP there is no filtering of data on top of a single data source. While in WPF it was possible to use the same `ObservableCollection` of items and filter only when binding your views using a [CollectionViewSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource?view=netframework-4.8), it seems like the only solution is [having two different collections](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15f3c875-e321-4eac-92ae-2f6226c33355/uwpcollectionviewsource-filter?forum=wpdevelop) like you are doing.

> There is indeed no Filter property in the CollectionViewSource class for UWP so [...] you will have to filter the source collection itself (or use two different collections like you are already doing).

Surely you can remove the need to call `UpdateFavorites()` by hooking to the `PropertyChanged` event of your items and move them from one collection to the other when their `IsFavorite` property is set, like this:

```cs
public AppViewModel()
{
    // Subscribing to changes in collection of items
    ItemsList .CollectionChanged += ItemList_CollectionChanged;
}

private void ItemList_CollectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Here subscribe/unsubscribe to PropertyChanged event of each item
    //as they come and go in the collection
}

private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Here check IsFavorite property and add/remove the item from the favorites list.
    //You can even instantiate another type of viewmodel object specific to favorites items.
}
```

Regarding the MVVM pattern, I would advice to have a lightweight `ItemModel` model like you suggest and have a collection of them stored in your model. Then you could have two collections, one with `ItemViewMode` objects and one with `FavoriteItemViewModel` objects in your `AppViewModel`. You could also have a single `ItemViewModel` class with an `IsFavorite` property and use triggers and styles to have them display differently.